# SFTP security: Can't verify the identity of an IP

Tags: networking, nautilus, security, sftp

When I connect to `sftp://10.116.202.136` via Nautilus, I receive this message:

```
Can't verify the identity of “10.116.202.136 (10.116.202.136)”.

This happens when you log in to a computer the first time.

The identity sent by the remote computer is 
“xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx”.

If you want to be absolutely sure it is safe to continue, 
contact the system administrator.
```

And I have two options: `Cancel` and `Login anyway`

This question raises this question to me:

What are the potential risk for me when I am using `sftp` on a public network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model is called [trust on first use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use). You are required to manually verify the identity of the server you are connecting to for the first time. Once you verify, SFTP client will store the value locally and on subsequent connections, verify the sever's identity automatically be comparing it to the stored value. If it changed, it will display a warning of a possible man-in-the-middle attack.

You should check the server's signature via a separate channel (if it's a public one, for example by checking the HTTPS website that lists its value, or as suggested by contacting the system administrator) and compare it with the one displayed by the SFTP client.

If you don't verify you are running into a risk of connecting to a hostile server which might serve different/modified versions of the files if you download, or might reveal the contents of the files you upload to the (malicious) server owner.

Comment: Thank, is there any chance of stealth of the password that I enter if I connect to a wrong computer?

Comment: Q2: is there any risk due to change of the IP? I am connecting to another computer on the net while its IP is not static.

Comment: If you are using password authentication and connect to a malicious server, the server can of course read your password. With key-based authentication it's not possible.

Comment: I don't understand your Q2 at all.

Comment: Q2: Computer A connects to computer B through network while IP of computer B is dynamic. So is it possible that the IP of computer B changes to something else and its previous IP is given to computer C. Therefore, now computer A is now connecting to computer C by mistake. Does it bring any security risk?

Comment: Please try to understand the answer: "If [the signature] changed, it will display a warning of a possible man-in-the-middle attack."